# How to put citations in footnote using square bracket style?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I would like the simple command `\cite` produces an entry in the bibliography (at the end of the doc) and in the footnote, using the format:

```
bla bla bla~\cite{myref} bla bla.
```

whose result is:

bla bla bla [1] bla bla.

---

[1] author, journal, year

---

I have found this : [Biblatex cite with footnote only once, with use of brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20787/biblatex-cite-with-footnote-only-once-with-use-of-brackets)

[edit]: It is almost what I need, but without the superscript and with less information in the footnote (only author, journal, year, volume, page). But I have no idea how to do that.

[edit2]: I cannot find a solution. As I should send my thesis very soon, I am asking for help, once again. Many thanks.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Biblatex is rather easy to customise. What's complicated in using the  `\footcite` command?

Comment: I am sure it is true, but I do not know biblatex at all. I tried a simple example `\usepackage[citestyle=authortitle,bibstyle=numeric,url=true,isbn=false,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}` but it produces an exponent like a footnote. I would like a usual numeric citation [1] that produces a footnote and an entry in the biblio at the end (order by author, with a backref (cited on pages: 2, 3 and 5)

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific on your request: Do you want the number for the footnote to be a "label" for the entry (i.e. it should not change once assigned) or should it rather behave more like a footnote (that is, just increment by one each time) - and maybe interact with normal footnotes in numbering etc.? Is the number to be used in the bibliography. What is your preferred style in the bibliography? ...

Comment: What do you think of [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165899/35864) then? Just change the `style` to `numeric`. Of course you could then modify `morecite` to print author, journal and year.: `\newbibmacro*{morecite}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{journaltitle}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{year}}` (modulo line breaks after the `%`s, of course).

Comment: You are my hero! I love you <3. xD --->[] It seems to have some compatibility problems with my other packages. I will post my final solution, when (if) it works. thanks again.

Comment: arf, actually, it does not work because it is incompatible with the package ucs. I remove utf8x of inputenc package, but it does not change anything. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I found out. IT is the package boxedalign, from here http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/encadrer-une-ligne-dans-align-t8342.html that conflict. I did not know why, but I will see that later.

Answer (score 2):

After little modifying this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20787/biblatex-cite-with-footnote-only-once-with-use-of-brackets):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            hyperref=true,
            url=false,
            isbn=false,
            backref=false,
            style=numeric-comp,
            maxcitenames=3,
            maxbibnames=100,
            block=none]{biblatex}\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{manyfoot}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true,sorting=none}

% Citation footnotes: use \footnoteA
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

% Vanilla footnotes: use \footnoteB
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\normalfont[\@thefnmark]\enspace #1}
    {\mkbibsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}



%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\bfcite}[\bracketing]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   %\let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{bfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{bfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\bracketing}[1]{%
  \mkbibbrackets{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatother

\addbibresource{example_ref_list.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation\bfcite{Torquato2002}.
First citation\bfcite[e.g.][530]{Bernal1959}.
Vanilla footnote\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text 2.}.
First ``multi'' citation\bfcite{Bernal1960,Bernal1959}.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Brackets footnotes and vanilla footnotes]